# Vim: refined paragraph jumping for tex files

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to change the behaviour of `{` and `}` in vim for tex files.

In tex files paragraphs are typically separated by one or more blank lines.

The cursor should be placed similarly to nroff macros (e.g. `.sh`) on the first line of the paragraph not on the separating blank line. Afaik, adjusting `:set paragraphs` does not allow this ([see here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/50.html#nroff-files)).

Noteworthy corner cases would be: `\indent`, `\noindent`, `\paragraph{}`, `\subparagraph{}` and probably more. Unfortunately, a comprehensive solution would be very complicated, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13085/in-how-many-ways-can-you-create-a-paragraph-in-latex.

But I don't need this. Even when I use `\paragraph{}` I add a blank line before it.

So this question should be limited to blank lines and placing the cursor on the next non-blank line.

#### Remarks:

- mappings should not touch search history.
- `jumplist` should be modified (same behaviour as `{` and `}`).

This question is motivated by the plugin [`limelight.vim`](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim) by junegunn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be:

```
nnoremap g} :call search('^$\n\s*\zs\S')<CR>
nnoremap g{ :call search('^$\n\s*\zs\S', 'b')<CR>
```

#### Remaining issues:

- An improvement could be to treat closed folds (e.g. folded sections by plugin [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)) as a single paragraph.
- respect `'foldopen'` setting for block (same behaviour as `{` and `}`)
  This probably resolves the first issue as well.
- It is not possible to go to the beginning of the file.

---

#### Improved Mappings

```
nnoremap <silent> g} 
            \ :let old = @/
            \ <bar>/^$\n\s*\zs\S<CR>
            \ <bar>:nohlsearch
            \ <bar>call histdel('/', -1)
            \ <bar>let @/ = old<CR>
nnoremap <silent> g{
            \ :let old = @/
            \ <bar>?\(^$\n\s*\zs\S\)\<bar>\%^<CR>
            \ <bar>:nohlsearch
            \ <bar>call histdel('/', -1)
            \ <bar>let @/ = old<CR>
```

- do not pollute search history
- by setting `:set 'foldopen'` containing `block` and `search` (default anyway) same behaviour as `{` and `}` regarding folds
- `jumplist` is modified: using `CTRL-I` and `CTRL-O` cycles through these as well. (`:h jumplist`)
- allows going to the beginning of the file

#### Remaining issues II:

- `hlsearch` is switched off. if the user wants to keep the current search and wants to see them highlighted, mapping must be improved further. Probably flickering will occur.

#### Notes

- allows jumping from first paragraph to last by `g{` and from last to first with `g}` (not the same behaviour as `{` and `}`)
- `dg}` does not work (operator + `g}`/`g{`). In this case I prefer `d}` anyway.